# Intermittent Partial Filling of Tank

Tags: toilet

The toilet flushes and sometimes has a delay of a few minutes before starting to refill. Then after it is done, it seems like every couple hours it turns on again and partially fills like some water has leaked out and gone below a threshold.

[image: Inside of toilet tank]

Comment: Was not quite sure how to paste the picture or it did not work so here is a screenshare showing the inside of my tank...  https://www.screencast.com/t/Cvc8y9lUNsh1

Answer (score 1):

If the fill valve puts water into the reservoir every few hours this indicates that water is leaking through the flush flapper that neds to be replaced. If the fill valve does not flow water as soon as the toilet is flushed to refill the reservoir then the fill valve should be replaced. Both items are not expensive and are replaceable They can be purchased at Home Depot, Lowes, or any hardware or plumbing supply store.